# Xamarin.Forms on button click open popup with list of items

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

[image]

I have a button on command i need to load list from api an show in a popup. After that i need to choose one item from the list. Any suggestion how to import this? Similar like on the image!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Rg.Plugins.Popup` , which allows you to create custom popups as per your requirement.
Please refer: https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup